# How to control startup with joystick on sense hat

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sense

We are trying to write a code that starts raspberry pi when you hit the joystick of the sense hat.

Code that acknowledges when joy stick is pressed

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
sense = SenseHat()
while True: 
    for event in sense.stick.get_events():
        print(event.direction, event.action
```

outputs "middle pressed
middle released"

Now I need code that when I press middle and release it starts up the raspberry pi or more importantly turns it off.

Comment: Please don't forget to provide feedback to folks who have been kind enough to devise answers to your other, related questions.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." I have tried.

Comment: It will not be possible to **start** a Raspberry Pi with the Sense Hat joystick as all it does is send a keyboard  `Enter` key.

This must be handled by code within the operating system.

Shutdown is easy enough to do. Look for `python` code to send shutdown signal to a Linux system or send terminal commands from a script.